# Non-owning Eigen::MatrixXd

Tags: eigen, eigen3

I would like to matrix multiply data in `std::mdspan` i.e. have something like

```cpp
auto mat_mult(std::mdspan, std::mdspan) -> mdvector;
```

But as far as I can tell Eigen only supports owning `MatrixXd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be as confusing as possible, Eigen calls its non-owning type `Map`

```cpp
float data[] = {1,2,3,4};
Map<Vector3f> v1(data);       // uses v1 as a Vector3f object
Map<ArrayXf>  v2(data,3);     // uses v2 as a ArrayXf object
Map<Array22f> m1(data);       // uses m1 as a Array22f object
Map<MatrixXf> m2(data,2,2);   // uses m2 as a MatrixXf object
```

https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__QuickRefPage.html